# Why won't yum install the later release of an RPM when my custom RPM Requires that?

Tags: yum, rpm, rpm-spec

I created an RPM that has

```
Requires: ruby193-rubygem-passenger-native = 3.0.21-4.el6op
```

`yum deplist myrpm` says that `myrpm` requires that release and it's satisfied by that `rpm` which is in my repository. Yet, when I do "`yum update myrpm` at that point `yum` does not say that it will update to the newer release. Then, when I do `rpm -qa | grep passenger-native`, the 3.el6op release is still installed and not the 4.el6op release.

Why won't `yum` install the newer release? I can manually install the newer release, and no RPMs specifically require the older one.

Their RPM changed a file path and only incremented the release number and not the version number, so my RPM explicitly needs the newer release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rpm -qR myrm` prints what?

- `ruby193-rubygem-passenger-native`

or

- `ruby193-rubygem-passenger-native >= 3.0.21-4.el6op`

I would guess it is the first one. In that case `yum update myrpm` will update `myrpm` and dependencies which are needed. But `3.el6op` will satisfy that requires as well so it is not necessary to update that package. Plain `yum update` should update everything included that SCL package.

Comment: Actually, my output is the latter. I suppose yum simply doesn't care as much as I do that there is a higher release available.

Our workaround is to just change our update procedure to explicitly also update `ruby193-rubygem-passenger-native` which does pull down the newer release version we need.